# Getting error text outof PERL's $sftp->get or do {...}

Tags: perl, exception, sftp

I'm not a perl programmer but need to debug an error. I'm using the Net:SFTP:Foreign package.

When I attempt to get files, the following call fails:

$sftp->get(source, destination) or do { print "something went wrong."}

This line returns "something went wrong." What I would like is to find out WHAT went wrong! How can I extract the reason for failure?

By the way, this script has been working for months without an error. The script is very reliable, I just don't know how to capture the reason for failure.

Comment: The manual for the module is available [here](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.67/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I just realized I was using Net:SFTP:Foreign but trying to find error handling documentation for Net:SFTP!

Comment: Why the `do {print "something went wrong"}`? Can't you just use `print "something went wrong";`?

Comment: David, originally the brackets contained a lot more code, I removed all that and replaced with a simple print for this post...accidentally left the brackets in :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sftp->get($source, $destination)
   or print "something went wrong: " . $sftp->error . "\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$sftp->get(source, destination) or warn "get() failed with " . $sftp->error . "\n";
```

Comment: Using `warn` is an excellent idea instead of just `print`. Warn prints out to STDERR and automatically prints the line number if you don't end the line with a `\n`.

Comment: And, the 'warn' can easily be changed to 'carp' when the Carp module is used -- useful in larger contexts to pinpoint where in the code you are when you complained.